# Angular 2 Typescript: domain() is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an article class as defined like so:

```
export class Article {
  id : number; 
  isanon : boolean; 
  title: string;
  link: string;
  text: string; 
  subverse : string;
  userID : string;  
  votes: number;

  constructor(title: string, link: string, subverse : string, text : string, userID : string, votes?: number) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.text = text; 
    this.subverse = subverse; 
    this.userID = userID; 
    this.votes = votes || 0;
  }

  log() : void{
    console.log("Title: " + this.title + " Link: " + this.link + " subverse: " + this.subverse); 
  }

  domain(): string {
    try {
      const link: string = this.link.split('//')[1];
      return link.split('/')[0];
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  voteUp(): void {
    this.votes += 1;
  }

  voteDown(): void {
    this.votes -= 1;
  }


}
```

and I get the articles from the database using an observable service

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    articles : Article[];
```

and...

```
  this.service.GetArticles(this.subverseStr).subscribe( (data)=>{
    this.articles = <Article[]>data; 
  });
```

However, in my HTML template it doesn't recognize the domain() or any other TS functions.

```
<div class="meta">({{ article.domain() }})</div>
```

When the page is loaded, I get error:

```
core.umd.js:2837 EXCEPTION: Error in app/article/article.component.html:15:20 caused by: self.context.article.domain is not a function
```

It does recognize it as a function if I hard code my articles[] and it does recognize variable members. Any idea what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide the code for `GetArticles` and other relevant pieces. It isn't obvious at all that `data` is an array of `Article` instances, and it isn't obvious that `{{ article...` refers to `Article` instance. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is necessary.

Comment: GetArticles and other code can be found here:https://github.com/claysmith/hackerspulse/blob/master/wwwroot/app/services/app.service.hackerspulse.ts

Comment: `GetArticles` returns parsed JSON. It isn't `Article[]`. And can't have `domain` method.

Comment: @estus is there a way to convert JSON to Articles[]? Thanks.

Comment: Create an instance with `new Article(...)` that gets properties from JSON object.

Comment: @estus I'll mark as answer if you reply..

Comment: Ok, sure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetArticles` returns parsed JSON, it is a plain object from `res.json()`, not an array of instances of `Article`. So it can't have `domain` method.

`<Article[]>data` tricked typing system, so Typescript believes that it it is `Article[]` and doesn't warn on type mismatch.

It depends on what exactly is returned from server, should be something like

```
GetArticles(subverse : string) : Observable<Article[]>
{
    return this.http.get(...)
    .map(res => {
      let data: any = res.json();
      let dataArr: any[] = Object.values(data);

      return dataArr.map(({ title, link, ... }) => {
        return new Article(title, link, ...);
      });
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

I would suggest to move properties that are shared by `Article` and JSON response and  (`title`, `link`, ...) to common TypeScript interface, this can make types tighter.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the ().
Like that:

```
{{arcticle.domain}}
```

This is basically a pointer to your function and Angular2 will manage to call that function

Comment: it's just empty when I try it without parenthesis. Like blank string.

Comment: @estus Why isn't it a function when I defined it as such in my class?

Comment: @ClaySmith Because the thing you're acquiring from `GetArticles` isn't an instance of `Article` class. It is plain object from `res.json()`. You've tricked typing system with `<Article[]>data`, so Typescript believes that it it is `Article[]` and doesn't warn on type mismatch.